# iframe not working in tinymce when valid_elements defined

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-3

As soon as I define any valid_elements and/or extended_valid_elements I cannot insert iframe (iframe defined among valid_elements, extended_valid_elements)

All online samples with iframe support and valid_elements are with tinymce v3
and in v3 it works http://fiddle.tinymce.com/cTeaab/2

But in v4 it does not http://jsfiddle.net/armandsp/ug247bsm/

```
valid_elements : "a[href|target=_blank],strong,u,p,iframe[src|frameborder|style|scrolling|class|width|height|name|align]",
extended_valid_elements : "iframe[src|frameborder|style|scrolling|class|width|height|name|align]"
```

Comment: what is the issue -- seems like it's working to me? example domain just doesn't have content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not an issue with `valid_elements and/or extended_valid_elements` its a syntax error.

```
plugins: [
    "code",
    "media"
]
```

it should look like the following, plugins separated by spaces

```
plugins:"code autolink",
```

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:plugins

It doesn't support iframes if you enable `media` plugin

example :  http://jsfiddle.net/ug247bsm/7/

Comment: Thank you for the corrections. Strange that the media plugin (which by itself accepts iframes) does not accept iframe when valid_elements defined. My clients love the "insert video" option, but I guess I`ll have to make my own custom button.

Answer (score 0):

That's the solution to the problem, nothing else is needed:

https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22257

> I had a lot of trouble with this until I realised you have to select the correct TinyMCE panel set before editing the Prohibited elements. Choose the set that is assigned to administrator and editor.

Credits to the author!